# Can I get a Qatar visa on arrival coming from India, I have UAE residence visa

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, visas-on-arrival, qatar

Can I come to Qatar directly from India via Qatar airways if I have a UAE residence visa? manager position in UAE visa.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the profession listed on your visa is in [this list of 201 professions (PDF)](http://www.moi.gov.qa/site/english/departments/PassportDept/resources/2011/01/20_20401.pdf), and your residency and passport has more than 6 months validity - you can get a one-time single entry visit visa on arrival.

You can also get a visa for your dependents; as long as they have residency in UAE as well.

This means, if your wife is accompanying you; but she doesn't have residency in the UAE - she is not eligible for visa on arrival and will need a separate visa.